# Can't find dhcp configuration file

Tags: dhcp-server

I've installed dhcp server on my ubuntu natty (11.04) by typing this:
    `sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server`
but, I can't locate the dhcp configuration file (dhcpd.conf) in /etc/dhcp3/ or in /etc/dhcp/

and, when i try to run the service by typing
   `/etc/init.d/dhcp3-server start`
it comes : No such file or directory

Where can I locate the dhcp configuration file?
And, what should I do to start the dhcp service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `isc-dhcp-server` is provided by the generic `dhcp-server` package, so the init-script you are looking for is `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server`. The configuration file should be under `/etc/dhcp`, according to the package list here http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/isc-dhcp-server/filelist